# fastest algorithm for rectangular linear assignment problem

Tags: time-complexity, assignment-problem

I want to optimally assign $m$ jobs equally to $n$ workers, where $m>n$. Assume $m = an$ for some integer $a$, so that each worker must get exactly $a$ jobs. (The rectangular linear assignment problem, as defined [here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/220462021_Solving_the_Rectangular_assignment_problem_and_applications)). I know this can be done by duplicating the workers to have $a$ copies of each, and then solving using the Kuhn-Munkres algorithm, which would result in $O(m^3)$.

This is an upper bound on the complexity of my problem. Is it also a lower bound? Is my problem in fact $\Theta(m^3)$? I.e., is the method of duplicating workers and using Kuhn-Munkres (as fast as) the fastest algorithm for solving the rectangular linear assignment problem (RLAP)?.

I want to know because I have a reduction of RLAP to another problem, and I want to lower-bound the complexity of this other problem.

Comment: What is the "rectangular linear assignment problem"?

Comment: "The rectangular assignment problem is a generalization of the linear assignment problem (LAP): one wants to assign a number of persons to a smaller number of jobs, minimizing the total corresponding costs" - https://www.researchgate.net/publication/220462021_Solving_the_Rectangular_assignment_problem_and_applications

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, $\Omega(m^3)$ is not a lower bound.  Your problem can be solved in $O((nm)^{1 + o(1)} \log a)$ time,   by [reducing to max flow](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/51804/5038) and then using a state-of-the-art min cost max flow algorithm, such as the recent algorithm by [Chen et al](https://arxiv.org/abs/2203.00671).  See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_flow_problem#Algorithms.

There is a trivial $\Omega(nm)$ lower bound, since you have a weight for each pair of worker and job, and it requires $\Omega(nm)$ just to read in all of those weights.

These two bounds are nearly matching.

Comment: Thanks, I guess this shows it is not $\Theta(m^3)$ anyway. What I am really interested in is a lower bound though.

Comment: @ludog, see revised answer, where I have corrected a mistake in my prior answer and provided a lower bound.  I answered the question you asked (is $\Omega(m^3)$ a lower bound?).   Feedback for the future: If what you really wanted was the best possible lower bound, it would be better to ask for that explicitly from the start.